# Dobiński's formula

Tags: combinatorics

A derivation of Dobiński's formula is reproduced below. Why does the upper limit on the first sum change from $n$ to $\infty$ ? (See the red-boxed portion.)
[image: Dobiński's formula]

Comment: have you seen the change of integration for a double integral? I assume he permuted the order to take advantage of the close form of the inner summation.

Comment: Exactly, $$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{k}$$ is turned into $$\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{k\geq j} $$

Comment: In such a question, you should recall that $B(n)$ is the $n$th Bell number with a reference to a definition/explanation such as can be found in (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobiński's_formula). It is important that a text is self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that the inner sum is $0$ when $k>n$.

In fact, the inner sum $\sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^{k-j} {k\choose j} j^n$ is just $k!S(n,k)$, where $S(n,k)$ is the [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), which counts the number of ways of partitioning a set of $n$ elements into $k$ nonempty subsets.  Clearly, $S(n,k)=0$ when $k>n$.

Also important for the reindexing is that $S(n,0)=0$ when $n>0$, otherwise there would be a problem in the second step.

It would probably be simpler if we just wrote, from the start, $B(n) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty S(n,k)$, which is valid for $n\geq 0$.